# How to activate an environment in miniconda

Tags: python, conda, miniconda

I have to deal with python code on Windows, so I installed miniconda. The installer suggested not adding conda to the PATH, so I didn't. I have created an environment by using Anaconda Prompt `conda create -n playground python=3.6` command, but now I am confused. If I activate the environment by using `conda activate env` it only activates in the Anaconda Prompt shell and not anywhere else. If I start a cmder or an editor, it cannot find python or conda or pip or anything python related. How do I use conda environments outside of the Anaconda Prompt?

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is - you don't. The activation is literally just some changes to the environment variables, mainly `PATH`.
When you need to use a conda environment in some other program, you have two options:

- If the program doesn't know anything about Python, make sure that the program is started with the correct environment variables. E.g. just start it from within the shell with the activated conda environment.
- If the program does know about Python (e.g. some IDE), just point it to the correct `python` executable within the desired conda environment.

Comment: Hmm.... am I to understand that I have to start everything from the Anaconda Prompt? Why doesn't conda put itself in the PATH if it is required to activate environments?

Comment: You have to start everything from that Anaconda Prompt that requires the correct Python, yes. About adding `conda` to `PATH` - you have stated yourself that the installer suggested not to do it. Probably, because it can easily lead to massive confusion for some users. AFAIK, you can use `conda` from the Anaconda Prompt without modifying your `PATH` manually, so it's not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `conda` into `PATH`. Otherwise, `conda` and environment switches with command `conda` are only available within "Anaconda Prompt".

After adding `conda` in `PATH`, whic makes the command `conda` is available in every terminal, like `cmd.exe`, `powershell.exe` and "Anaconda Prompt".

"Anaconda Prompt" could be deemed as a **wrapper** of `cmd.exe` that does `conda activate base` for you automatically.

Answer (score 0):

> How do I use conda environments outside of the Anaconda Prompt?

Not sure if I get the "outside of Anaconda Prompt" correctly. But if you want to start the `miniconda` in say VScode's terminal, then the below method works for me.

If you don't want to add `conda` into `PATH`. The other way is to use the activation script in the `miniconda` folder to activate your `venv`.

1. Look for your `miniconda` location.
   For example, my `miniconda` is located in `C:\Users\User\miniconda3`
2. Navigate to `~\miniconda3\Scripts` and copy the path of `activate.bat`
   (i.e, copy `C:\Users\User\miniconda3\Scripts\activate.bat`)
3. Open a command prompt, paste, and execute the above bat file.
   Your `miniconda` should be activated, and you can use your `conda` command now.

This way you leave `conda` outside the `PATH`, but the downside is that you will need to do this everytime you want to activate your venv.